# Concatenate varbinary values and ignore the null ones?

Tags: sql-server

The following code

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(a as varbinary(max))) FROM (select 0 a, null b) t
```

returns `0x9069CA78E7450A285173431B3E52C5C25299E473`.

And the following code return null.

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(a as varbinary(max)) 
    + cast(b as varbinary(max)) 
    + cast(c as varbinary(max))
FROM (select 0 a, null b, null c) t -- There may be many columns
```

I tried to convert the null to 0, but the hash changed.

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(a as varbinary(max)) 
    + isnull(cast(b as varbinary(max)), 0)) 
    + isnull(cast(c as varbinary(max)), 0)) 
FROM (select 0 a, null b, null c) t
```

How to ignore the null `varbinary` values when concatenating?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the location of `isnull()` calls like this:

`select hashbytes('SHA1', cast(isnull(a, '') as varbinary(max)) + cast(isnull(b, '') as varbinary(max)) + cast(isnull(c, '') as varbinary(max))) FROM (select 0 a, null b, null c) t;`

I have tested it in SQL Server 2012.